# history.createBrowserHistory is not a function in Jest test using React

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I saw the following error in the Chrome console:

```
warnAboutDeprecatedCJSRequire.js:17 Warning: Please use `require("history").createBrowserHistory` instead of `require("history/createBrowserHistory")`. Support for the latter will be removed in the next major release.”
```

To resolve this warning, I changed:

```
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';

export default createHistory();
```

to:

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';

const history = createBrowserHistory();

export default history;
```

This correctly resolved the warning, however many of the Jest tests now fail with the following error: "TypeError: (0 , _history.createBrowserHistory) is not a function"

The project is using:

- react 16.4.1
- redux 4.0.0
- react-router-dom 4.2.2

Comment: why you use history npm package in the first place? react-router version 4 has an history object on its API, you don't need to explicitly build it yourself.

Comment: if you use jest for unit-testing(not acceptance testing) you anyway need to mock `global.history`. do you mock it?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code fix error, This function is not defined when jest in run.

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history"

const history = createBrowserHistory ? createBrowserHistory() : []

export default history
```